# Python Pandas Change Column to Headings

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the following format: [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PQ2e.png)

This data is loaded into a pandas dataframe. The date column is the index for this dataframe. How would I have it so the names become the column headings (must be unique) and the values correspond to the right dates.

So it would look something like this:

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtycV.png)

Comment: Look into pivot_table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split out the column’s values, then rename your dataframe’s columns, and then you can `pivot()` the dataframe. I have added the steps below:

```
df[0].str.split(' ' , expand = True) # assumes you only have the one column
df.columns = ['col_name','values'] # use whatever naming convention you like 
df.pivot(columns = 'col_name',values = 'values')
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following toy `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y':['0 a','2 a','3 b','0 b']})
>>> df
   x    y
0  1  0 a
1  2  2 a
2  3  3 b
3  4  0 b
```

Start by processing each row into a `Series`:

```py
>>> new_columns = df['y'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict([reversed(x.split())])))
>>> new_columns
     a    b
0    0  NaN
1    2  NaN
2  NaN    3
3  NaN    0
```

Alternatively, new columns can be generated using `pivot` (the effect is the same):

```py
>>> new_columns = df['y'].str.split(n=1, expand=True).pivot(columns=1, values=0)
```

Finally, concatenate the original and the new `DataFrame` objects:

```py
>>> df = pd.concat([df, new_columns], axis=1)
>>> df
   x    y    a    b
0  1  0 a    0  NaN
1  2  2 a    2  NaN
2  3  3 b  NaN    3
3  4  0 b  NaN    0
```

Drop any columns that you don't require:

```py
>>> df.drop(['y'], axis=1)
   x    a    b
0  1    0  NaN
1  2    2  NaN
2  3  NaN    3
3  4  NaN    0
```